# Centering a link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to center a bordered READ MORE link on a web page, but haven't succeeded yet. The link still sits on the left of the page:

[image]

I'm using Twitter Boostrap and that's how the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="more"><a href="#">read more</a></h2>
</div> <!--end container-->
```

And the CSS:

```
#process .more {
    border: 1px solid #392e2e;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#process .more a {
    color: #392e2e;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

I've also tried it with Bootstrap's class="text-center", but that doesn't work either. [Here's](http://skiest.ragne.me/) a link to my project, you can see the READ MORE link issue at the very bottom of the page.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the text-center class but use it on the parent div container for the link:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2 class="text-center more"><a href="#">read more</a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

### 1. Block display method:

```
#process .more a {
    color: #392e2e;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    width:100px; //Adjustable and depends on you
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or:

### 2. Outer element align:

```
h2.more {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}

h2.more a {
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with 2 examples: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6o7Larv/)

There are actually other ways to do it with CSS, but these two are the most common.